# Catching function failure within a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to catch a failure of a function within a loop in R. I want to return `NA` and move on to continue to execute the loop.

The function `glm.nb` fails at j=1328, i=1, and thereafter fills all the `MLEb_d0` and `MLEb_d1` slots with missing values.

I would like to catch the error, returning for both `MLEb_d0` and `MLEb_d1`, and move on to
j=1329 correctly:

```
# Now get MLE parametric bootstrap solutions, matching the TMM 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
require(foreign)
require(ggplot2)
require(MASS)

MLEb_d0 <- matrix(nrow=2000, ncol=500)
MLEb_d1 <- matrix(nrow=2000, ncol=500)

for (i in 1:2){
      yy <- as.matrix(sample[[i]])

      for(j in 1:2000){
        yyy1 <- as.vector(yy[j,])
        yv <- cbind(yyy1,TMM, design_tdDESeq); 
        yv <- as.data.frame(yv)

        m <- summary(m1 <- glm.nb(yyy1 ~ -1 + timed0 + timed1
              + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6
              + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10 + p11 + p12
              + p13 + p14 + p15, data = yv, offset(TMM)))
        MLEb_d0[j,i] <- m$coefficients[1,4]
        MLEb_d1[j,i] <- m$coefficients[2,4] 
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you even looked at `try()` or `tryCatch()`?

Comment: [Here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r/12195574#12195574) that asks about how to implement `tryCatch`

Comment: The function `foreach()` in package `foreach` allows you to this very easily.